# How to not get data to overwritten in firebase and store an attribute as a list of items?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Whenever I click on the SAVE Button to save the name and number, the skills field is being overwritten.

[Here the image of Activity while storing details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh4La.png)

Also please help me to get the skills as a list instead of creating new skilladd every time. Also new skills must be appended to the list without overwriting.

/**** ACCOUNT.JAVA ****/

```
package com.coginitoamicis.coginitoamicis;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class Account extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText accname;
private EditText accnumb;
private EditText accskill;

private Button accsave;
private Button accskilladd;

private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()==null){
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
    }

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    accname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accname);
    accnumb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accnumb);
    accsave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accsave);

    accskill = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accskill);
    accskilladd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accskilladd);

    accsave.setOnClickListener(this);
    accskilladd.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void userdatasave(){

    String name = accname.getText().toString().trim();
    String numb = accnumb.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){
        //name is empty
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please Enter your Name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(numb)){
        //number is empty
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please Enter your Mobile Number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    UserInformation userInformation = new UserInformation(name, numb);

    FirebaseUser user =firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(userInformation);

    Toast.makeText(this,"Information Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

private void skilldatasave(){

    String skill = accskill.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(skill)){
        //skills is empty
        Toast.makeText(this,"Enter Skill to Proceed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    Skilladd skilladds = new Skilladd(skill);

    FirebaseUser user =firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).push().setValue(skilladds);

    Toast.makeText(this,"Skills Added Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (view == accsave){
        userdatasave();
    }

    if (view == accskilladd){
        skilldatasave();
    }

}
}
```

/**** USERINFORMATION.JAVA ****/

```
package com.coginitoamicis.coginitoamicis;

public class UserInformation {

public String name;
public String numb;

public UserInformation(String name, String numb){
    this.name = name;
    this.numb = numb;
}


}
```

/**** SKILLADD.JAVA ****/

```
package com.coginitoamicis.coginitoamicis;


public class Skilladd {

public String skill;

public Skilladd(String skill){
    this.skill = skill;
}
}
```

Comment: hello you take skill in string array whenever you add detail.so you easily get in listing and not override data.

Comment: how can i do that?
should i take an array in the java file?
how will i append new skills to the array in firebase?

Comment: normal as use in java we can add.and then pass in adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Push()

```
Firebase newsPush = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);
            final News news = new News();
            news.setNewsTitle(newsTitleString);
            news.setNewsDetails(newsDetailsString);
            newsPush.push().setValue(news);
```

Create Getters and Setters for Object

```
public class News implements Serializable {

private String newsTitle;
private String newsDetails;
private String newsDate;
private String newsPicUrl;

/*news Model to get and set news data*/
public String getNewsTitle() {
    return newsTitle;
}

public void setNewsTitle(String newsTitle) {
    this.newsTitle = newsTitle;
}

public String getNewsDetails() {
    return newsDetails;
}

public void setNewsDetails(String newsDetails) {
    this.newsDetails = newsDetails;
}
```

Comment: Firebase newsPush = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);         Firebase is not working for me??

Comment: FIREBASE_URL = "your firebase database url" you directly define it as `private final String FIREBASE_URL = "your_firebase_datbase_url"; `

Answer (score 0):

Use this on oncreate

```
    keysArray = new ArrayList<>();
    valuesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, displayArray);
    listView.setAdapter(valuesAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

    rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    rootRef.addChildEventListener(childEventListener);

    save.setOnClickListener(this);
```

here i use this code onSAve click:

```
    private void save(String name, String message) {

    rootRef.child(name).setValue(message, new CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            nameEditText.setText("");
            messageEditText.setText("");
            hideProgressBar();
        }
    });
}
```

and here use child listner :

```
    ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Log.d(TAG, dataSnapshot.getKey() + ":" + dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
        String keyAndValue = "Name: " + dataSnapshot.getKey().toString() + "\t Messsage: " + dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
        displayArray.add(keyAndValue);
        keysArray.add(dataSnapshot.getKey().toString());
        updateListView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        String changedKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
        int changedIndex = keysArray.indexOf(changedKey);
        String keyAndValue = "Name: " + dataSnapshot.getKey().toString() + "\t Messsage: " + dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
        displayArray.set(changedIndex, keyAndValue);
        updateListView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String deletedKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
        int removedIndex = keysArray.indexOf(deletedKey);
        keysArray.remove(removedIndex);
        displayArray.remove(removedIndex);
        updateListView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Log.d(TAG, dataSnapshot.getKey() + ":" +     dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }


};
```